# Panda не отображает кирилицу при чтении excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, кириллица

Пытаюсь посмотреть эксель файл в кодировке cp1251 выдаёт:

РџСЂРѕРµРєС‚РёСЂСѓРµРјС‹Р№

```
pd.read_excel(r'R:\TEST1.xlsx',sep='None')
```

Что можно добавить в код чтобы нормально выводило кириллицу

Варианты ниже не помогли:

```
pd.read_excel(r'R:\TEST1.xlsx',sep='None', encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding())
pd.read_excel(r'R:\TEST1.xlsx',sep='None', encoding=('cp1251'))
pd.read_excel(r'R:\TEST1.xlsx',sep='None', encoding=("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Пробовали искать похожие вопросы? Вопросы про python и кириллицу задаются каждый день, и это не преувеличение

Comment: @dIm0n искал и находил но те решения мне не помогли

Comment: Так приведите в вопросе решения, которые вы использовали. Сейчас кто-то потратит своё время, дав решение, а вы скажете "я пробовал, не помогло"? Используйте кнопку править

Comment: Укажите правильную кодировку при чтении файла

Comment: encoding="cp1251"

Comment: Если выдает РџСЂРѕРµРєС‚РёСЂСѓРµРјС‹Р№ - это верный знак того, что фактическая кодировка UTF-8, а не cp1251

Comment: @insolor посмотрел через notepad++ там написано windows-1251

Comment: @Grechkin26, два независимых вопроса: 1 - то есть вы бинарный файл открыли текстовым редактором, и он какие-то вменяемые данные вам показал? 2 - ну а кодировку utf-8 пробовали указать при открытии файла?

Comment: @insolor 1) нет не показал 2) да указывал результат тот же. Я конечно могу что то неправильно делать но из того массива инфы что я нашел вроде все делаю верно

Comment: 1 - если не показал, значит его показаниям (кодировке, которую он показал) нельзя верить :) Вообще, кодировка, которую показывает текстовый редактор при открытии бинарного файла не говорит ни о чем. 2 - насколько я вижу по документации, у метода [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) вообще нет параметра encoding. В общем, нужно разбираться.

Comment: @insolor по той инфе что нашел в интернете все используют encoding хотя да в документации этого нет но кому помогает а кому нет

Comment: @Grechkin26 encoding и sep имеют смысл для read_csv. Возможно вы видели примеры для таких файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании следующей конструкции :

```
dc=pd.read_excel(r'R:\TEST.xlsx')
print (dc)
```

кириллица отображается нормально